# Simple template to pass a c++ member method as a callback

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a set of classes which have many very similar methods, grouped into 2 call signatures. These calls are of the form:

`bool fn( const std::string& )` and `bool fn( const std::vector<std::string>& )`

I need to do some common logic around each call and I'm trying to make my life easy but without much luck. Conceptually, the wrapper logic signature looks like the following:

`bool wrap( config::method, key, values, flag )`

I have code that compiles but it is more complicated than I want. This is the actual signature (there will be two wrappers, one for each signature type):

```
template <typename T, bool(T::*fn)(const std::string&)>
bool CFG_STR( T& cfg, const char* key, Nodes data, bool flag ) { /* ... cfg.*fn(x) ... */ }
```

and this is the caller:

```
configClassWithVeryLongName config;
success &= CFG_STR<
    configClassWithVeryLongName,
    &configClassWithVeryLongName::methodCall
>( config, "key", dataStore, configFlag );
```

Is there a more compact and less fragile way to write this? I can reduce it to this:

```
#define MAC_STR(c,m,k,d,f) CFG_STR<typeof( c ), m>( c, k, d, f )

configClassWithVeryLongName config;
success &= MAC_STR( config, &configClassWithVeryLongName::methodCall, "key", dataStore, configFlag );
```

I would really like to remove the class name prefix and simply pass `methodCall` or "methodCall", and not use CPP macros. Is there a clever way to do this cleanly? I've tried a few things like combining `typeof` with the `#` paste macro to form the method name but without any success. Modifying the 'config...' classes is not an option because they do not all inherit from a common base class.

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: `typeof` is not standard C++, use `decltype` instead.

Comment: "I have a set of classes which have many very similar methods," Do you have many classes or do you have a class with many similar methods or do you really have many classes with many similar methods. Only the last one needs the function pointer stuff! BTW: In times of having lambda in place, it might be easier to write the callback online instead of having all the wrappers and callers and mixins in place.

Comment: Side note 2: `cfg.*fn(x)` (from comment): `.*` operator has lower priority than function call operator, thus you need additional parentheses: `(cfg.*fn)(x)`.

Comment: @Klaus Depending on what's intended the function pointer stuff might fit one class with many member functions as well, but no *template* needed then.

Comment: If you *do* rely on function pointers you won't get around `&ClassName::memberFunction` syntax, no matter if hidden behind a macro or not. The function pointer should be a *function* parameter instead of a *template* parameter, but that doesn't avoid the syntax. C++ doesn't come with integrated reflection, so something like `getFunction(object, "member function name"` does not exist within standard C++ and can only be tried to be simulated via macros.

Comment: @Klaus - I have many classes with many similar methods. Many are derivations of each other. They are all configuring different types of objects, each with many properties. But the input is always a string or vector of strings. Eg, Animal->{Bird,Mammal}->etc.

Comment: @Aconcagua - Thanks for the notes. 'decltype' was giving me different problems, I think in part, because I'm actually using a reference. I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out (despite the downvote) and another SO answer with the templated argument got me the closest. The answer below clarifies greatly.

Comment: Why don't you pass the method pointer as argument? Then both template types could be deduced and you can just leave them out or use auto. Also consider lambdas.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thanks - I was overcomplicating the problem. I'm not using lambdas because I think I would need one (or two if it has array parameters) inside each configuration parsing function, when all I really need are two global wrapper functions that apply to dozens of different classes and methods. The solution that was proposed below works, given a relatively minor tweak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just pass the member pointer as function argument:

```
template <typename T>
bool CFG_STR( T& cfg, bool(T::*fn)(const std::string&), const char* key, Nodes data, bool flag ) { /*...*/ }
```

And instead of repeating the class name you can just write `decltype(config)`:

```
success &= CFG_STR( config, &decltype(config)::methodCall, "key", dataStore, configFlag );
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, but my 'config' is actually a VeryLongName& so I get the error: "Result of decltype qualifier 'VeryLongName &' is not a class". I tried using "decltype((config))" because I think it should remove the reference but doesn't. If I change all my function signatures to start with `set`, I can use this: `#define MAC_STR(c,m,k,d,f) CFG_STR( c, &std::decay_t<decltype(c)>::set##m, k, d, f)`. Is that the best option? It does make the caller what I wanted.

Comment: @rand'Chris It should be `std::remove_reference_t<decltype(config)>` then, which doesn't look that nice anymore, but you can just use a `using` declaration for the type before you use it in the variable definition. I don't like having macros at all, so I would not choose that approach.